# why R generating error when i try to pass argument to the if function

Tags: r

here i am giving the code

```
#my user defined function
my.display<-function(x,display=TRUE,type="hist",prob=TRUE)
{

  if(display=TRUE)
print("1")

  else hist(x)

  if(type=hist) hist(x) elseif(type=density) plot(density(x))
  cat("Please specify type as either hist or density")

  if(prob=TRUE) hist(x,freq=TRUE) else hist(x,freq=TRUE)
  }
```

the error r shows is when it passes to the if(display=TRUE), I believe the expression is wrong or something. if the display=TRUE argument then it should print 1 else generate a histogram of the vector x.

`if(type=hist)` also showing error . someone please help.

Comment: maybe `==` instead of  `=`

Answer (score 2):

`=` acts as assign operator same as `<-` operator in R

while `==` is a logical operator.

So you should use `if(display == TRUE)`. You might also want to add some `{}` in your if-else structures for readability.

Try this code for second doubt

## updated:

```
my.display<-function(x,display,type,prob=TRUE)
{if(display==TRUE){
    print("1")
  }
  else 
  if(type=="hist") {hist(x)}
  else
    if(type=="density") {plot(density(x))}
  else
  cat("Please specify type as either hist or density")
  if(prob==TRUE){ hist(x,freq=TRUE)}
  else 
    hist(x,freq=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: thank you it did work, if you look at the same code for the third argument type="hist". i want to generate histogram or if type="density" a density plot.